# Local prediction modelling approach in R

Tags: r, local

users

I am trying to develop a local model (PLSR) which is predicting a query sample by a model built on the 10 most similar samples  using the code below (not the full model yet, just a part of it). I got stuck when trying to predict the query sample (second to last line). The model is actually predicting something, ("prd") but not the query sample!

Here is my code:

```
require("pls")
set.seed(10000)   # generate some sample data
mat <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))
y <- as.matrix(mat[,1], drop=F) 
x <- mat[,2:100]
eD <- dist(x, method="euclidean")    # create a distance matrix
eDm <- as.matrix(eD)
```

Looping over all 100 samples and extracting their 10 most similar samples for subsequent model building and prediction of query sample:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(eDm)) { 
     kni <- head(order(eDm[,i]),11)[-1]    # add 10 most similar samples to kni
     pls1 <- plsr(y[kni,] ~ x[kni,], ncomp=5, validation="CV")    # run plsr on sel. samples
prd <- predict(pls1, ncomp=5, newdata=x[[i]])    # predict query sample  ==>  I suspect there is something wrong with this expression: newdata=x[[i]]
}
```

I can't figure out how to address the query sample properly - many thanks i.a. for any help!

Best regards,

Chega

Comment: what package is `plsr` in?

Comment: It is in the **pls** package.

Comment: @Carson: Yes, Gavin is right - I used to pls package - sorry for missing to mention this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to run into all sorts of pain building models with formulae like that. Also the `x[[i]]` isn't doing what you think it is - you need to supply a data frame usually to these modelling functions. In this case a matrix seems fine too.

I get all your code working OK if I use:

```
prd <- predict(pls1, ncomp=5, newdata=x[i, ,drop = FALSE])
```

giving

```
> predict(pls1, ncomp=5, newdata=x[i,,drop = FALSE])
, , 5 comps

      y[kni, ]
[1,] 0.6409897
```

What you were seeing with your code are the **fitted** values for the training data.

```
> fitted(pls1)[, , 5, drop = FALSE]
, , 5 comps

     y[kni, ]
1   0.1443274
2   0.2706769
3   1.1407780
4  -0.2345429
5  -1.0468221
6   2.1353091
7   0.8267103
8   3.3242296
9  -0.5016016
10  0.6781804
```

This is convention in R when you either don't supply `newdata` or the object you are supplying makes no sense and doesn't contain the covariates required to generate predictions.

I would have fitted the model as follows:

```
pls1 <- plsr(y ~ x, ncomp=5, validation="CV", subset = kni)
```

where I use the `subset` argument for its intended purpose; to select the rows of the input data to fit the model with. You get nicer output from the models; the labels use `y` instead of `y[kni, ]` etc, plus this general convention will serve you well in other modelling tools, where R will expect `newdata` to be a data frame with `names` **exactly** the same as those mentioned in the model formula. In your case, with your code, that would mean creating a data frame with names like `x[kni, ]` which are not easy to do, for good reason!

Comment: @Ben Thanks. "label" was intended but even then didn't read well. Have fixed the typo.

Comment: @Gavin: Hmm, much easier than I expected- many thanks for this! I also  appreciate your comments regarding the formulae notation in R (with which I admittedly seem to be at war:() - definitely need to review this!